# LXDE ubuntu - can't hear speech, but hear background sound

Tags: sound, alsa

everyone.
When playing some online movies, the sound is corrupted - I cannot hear a speech, but can hear the "background" sounds. I use USB headphones, not regular 3.5mm jack. These headphones work well on other computers with either linux or win OP's.
I thought it was because of sound settings - analog stereo vs 5.1 stereo. Changing these setting didn't help.
What do I do? refresh Alsa settings? Reinstall Alsa?
Let me know what to do and how.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add which version of Ubuntu you are using. As you indicate LXDE as the desktop environment - there is no more Lubuntu version with support for LXDE.
In case you installed LXDE afterwards, please describe how.

Comment: For older/newer hardware changing kernel stack can make a difference, have you explored this?  We don't know what Ubuntu product/system you're using so can't be very specific (*default stack is set by installation media*)